# Should I get Windows 10, 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro, macOS Catalina with 16 GB RAM and a 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 processor and I want to download Windows 10 so that I can get games on steam that are only for Windows.

It’s giving me the option of the 32-bit download or the 64-bit download and I don’t know which one to choose...

Comment: You absolutely want the 64 bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It was answered in a comment, but you want the 64bit, else you can't allocate more the 4GB of RAM.

Comment: The Windows Support Software provided by Apple would only contain the drivers for a 64 bit install, so you really do not have a choice.